# How to add a "Contact me" form to a blog hosted on Blogger?

Tags: blogger

After doing some research, I know I need to create a new page and add a form to it.

- Is that the best way? Doesn't Blogger have appropriate built-in feature?
- What form service can you recommend? [EmailMeForm](http://www.emailmeform.com/), [Kontactr](http://kontactr.com/), [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/), other service?

I tried to use Google Forms, but the customization options are really poor (e.g. I couldn't remove the form header with its title and description).

Comment: I thought you'd be able to do this in Google Forms, but I couldn't get it to work. (This is one of the reasons I moved to Wordpress; it now has this built-in.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blogger now has a built in feature for this.   To use it, go to Layout, choose Add a Gadget, and then in the gadget-choice window, click More Gadgets.    Contact form is top of the list.     Complete the details, save the form layout - any you will have a contact feature in the sidebar or footer or header (wherever you put the gadget).

If you want it to look like it is on a page, then

1. Position it just below the Blog Posts gadget
2. Make a page called something like Contact, and link to it from your
   menu etc
3. Set it up so that you only display the gadget on that specific page.
   (Instructions for this [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.ie/2010/03/displaying-gadget-only-on-home-page.html).)

Alternatively, Google Forms has developed a lot in the last couple of years, so you could easily make a contact-me form in it.    However this will put the messages left into a Google Sheets spreadsheet, not email them to you.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to use Google Forms, but the customization options are really poor (e.g. I couldn't remove the form header with its title and description).

This is news to me - I was able to create a complete Google forms solution (with automatic reply script 'TTResponse') very easily and customise it for my needs.

Prehaps you should take another look?

My inspiration can from [here.](http://www.clickonf5.org/google/replace-blog-forms-google-docs/1648)

My form is online [here.](http://rdturner.co.uk/Kontakt.html)

Comment: But you didn't need to remove form's title (*Kontakt aufnehmen*) and description (*Sie können mit Hilfe dieses Formulars ...*), while I have to.

Comment: Could you replace it with a space?

Comment: Oh yes, I see what you mean. I put an underscore in the top line, as when I left it blank it wasn't happy.

Comment: add ttl=0 to the url to hide the title of the form

Answer (score 1):

You can simply embed a contact form on your blogspot blog using Google drive forms http://www.ogbongeblog.com/2012/08/how-i-create-contact-form-for-blogger.html